# Как читать файлы в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

В HTML есть тег input, в том числе он позволяет выбирать файлы: `<input type="file">`.

Мне нужно, чтобы код на javascript получил содержимое файла. Как работать с файлами в JavaScript?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/file

Comment: с лево на право)

Comment: Какой файл вы хотите прочитать? Наверное, *psd*, *zip*, *mp3* или *docx*?

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/file) написано несколько вариантов, как вы можете прочитать файл. В этом примере содержимое файла будет находиться в reader.result

```
<input type="file" onchange="readFile(this)">

<script>
function readFile(input) {
  let file = input.files[0];

  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsText(file);

  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };

  reader.onerror = function() {
    console.log(reader.error);
  };

}
</script>
```